# Returning sql query result via Ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the result in asp x page in text box using ajax call based on employee id.
I have written Sq l query as a web method to get the results.Its returning list<> of records.I want to show the result on asp x page using JavaScript ajax calls in input text box via Sq l query.For e.g.  dB table name is Employee Records with First-name,Last-name,Email.I want to get the records via Sq l query in web method and then want to display via ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://localhost:12897/Methods.asmx/GetEmployeeById",
                data: '{"pid": "' + value + '"}',
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {

                    response = true;
                    $('#testerror').html();// i want query result here in text box with id testerror
                    $('#confirmModal').modal();

                },
                error: function (result) {

                    alert("please try again");
                    return false;

                }

            });
```

Comment: what is the value of msg?

Comment: Query is returning from webmethod.i need to display the columns obtained from it in  success message.

Comment: db.Fetch<EmployeeRecords>(sql).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

$('#testerror').html(msg.d);

try this, it will take the response from the server and place it into your testerror.  Assuming testerror is an object with the .html property.

If that doesn't work you could try .val(msg.d) instead of .html(msg.d)

---

This will display the response back from your server call.  If you need to format them as an HTML table please clarify that.

Comment: i want to return the data obtained from sql query and then display it  in html properties(textbox)

Comment: Is it returning desired output in ajax success call?